# How to make a button invisible in odoo 10

Tags: xml, inheritance, xpath, odoo-10, odoo

I'm trying to hide this button under sale module. So this is the original code:

```
    <button name="%(action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" 
              string="Create Invoice"
              type="action" class="btn-primary"
              attrs="{'invisible': [('invoice_status', '!=', 'to invoice')]}"/>
```

So I inherited the view and created this code:

```
    <xpath name="//header/button[@name='%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d']" position="attributes"> 
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute> 
    </xpath>
```

But when running this code I got this error:

```
raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `name` instead of `expr` as an attribute of `xpath`:

```
<xpath expr="//header/button[@name='%(sale.action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d']" position="attributes"> 
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute> 
</xpath>
```

That should be the problem.

Comment: wow. I can't sometimes believe it when I go back and see what I wrote.. like if I was blind. Thanks!!